# If statement doesn't work with Pandas(csv) element

Tags: python, pandas, database

My code is quite simple, and so the question, this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

def main():
    #usernames and passwords
    users = "usernames,passwords\nSimone,123456"
    #login
    def login_system():
        login = input("Login or SignUP: ")
        if login == "Login" or login == "login":
            #data reading 
            df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(users), usecols=["usernames", "passwords"])
            username = input()
            password = input()
            #login if statement
            if username == df["usernames"][0] and password == df["passwords"][0]:
                print("Login Succeeded")
            else:
                print("Login Failed")
        return
    login_system()
    return
main()
```

it compiles and everything the problem is that it doesn't do what it is supposed to, here is the answer that the compiler gives

```
Login or SignUP: Login
Simone
123456
Login Failed
```

Could someone explain to me why the if statement doesn't work

Comment: `df["passwords"][0]` is an `int` and `password` is a string.

Comment: Use `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(users), usecols=["usernames", "passwords"], dtype={'passwords': str})` if password should explicitly be string, or add some non-numeric values to the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to look up whether the username and password matches the entry in the csv file that you read into the df.  You can filter the df to check if any row matches both username and password.  If there is any such row, you have a match.  See this toy example:

```
row1list = ['Simone', 'password1']
row2list = ['YEETter', 'password2']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list], columns=['usernames', 'passwords'])

username = 'Simone'
password = 'password1'

dfu = df[(df['usernames'] == username) & (df['passwords'] == password)]
print(dfu)
#   usernames  passwords
# 0    Simone  password1

if len(dfu) > 0:
    print("Login Succeeded")
else:
    print("Login Failed")
```